# Let $X_1,...,X_n \sim N(\theta,\sigma^2)$. Show that the test rejecting $H_0$ when $\bar X > t_{n-1,\alpha}\sqrt{S^2/n}$ is a test of size $\alpha$.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Assuming that the test is $H_0: \theta \leq 0$ vs. $H_1: \theta > 0$, $\sigma^2$ is unknown, and $t_{n-1,\alpha}$ is the $(1-\alpha)$th percentile of a t-distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom, I need to show that this test is of size $\alpha$, and that it can be derived as a generalized LRT.

Edit:

I think I finally found the LRT statistic (which I guess is the first step)

\begin{align}
\lambda(x_1...x_n) &= \frac{sup_{\theta_0\leq0,\sigma_0}L(\theta_0,\sigma_0|x_1...x_n)}{sup_{\theta,\sigma}L(\theta,\sigma|x_1...x_n)} \\
&=\frac{sup_{\theta_0\leq0,\sigma_0}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_0^2}}\right)^nexp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma_0^2}\sum\left(x_i-\theta_0\right)^2\right)}{sup_{\theta,\sigma}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right)^nexp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum\left(x_i-\theta\right)^2\right)} \\
&=\frac{sup_{\sigma_0}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_0^2}}\right)^nexp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum x_i^2\right)}{sup_{\sigma}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right)^nexp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum\left(x_i-\bar x\right)^2\right)} \\
&=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hat\sigma_0^2}}\right)^nexp\left(e^{-n/2}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hat\sigma^2}}\right)^nexp\left(e^{-n/2}\right)} \\
&=\left(\frac{\hat \sigma^2}{\hat \sigma_0^2}\right)^{n/2} \\
&=\left(\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2}{\sum x_i^2}\right)^{n/2}
\end{align}

I also know that for $H_0$ to be rejected,

$$\left(\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2}{\sum x_i^2}\right)^{n/2} > t $$
$$\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2}{\sum x_i^2} < t^{2/n}$$

but then how do I continue rearranging to show that $\bar X > t_{n-1,\alpha}\sqrt{S^2/n}$ and show that the test is of size $\alpha$?

Comment: But where are you stuck? Find the LRT statistic for starters.

Comment: Sure,

$$\lambda(x) = \frac{L(\theta_1|x)}{L(\theta_0|x)} = exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \left[\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\theta_1)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\theta_0)^2\right]\right)$$

Comment: LRT statistic is given by $$\lambda(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{\sup_{\theta\le 0,\sigma}L(\theta,\sigma\mid x_1,\ldots,x_n)}{\sup\limits_{\theta,\sigma}L(\theta,\sigma\mid x_1,\ldots,x_n)}$$

Comment: ok so is it this then? 

$$\lambda(x_1...x_n) = exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \left[\sum(x_i)^2 - \sum(x_i-\bar x)^2\right]\right)$$

Comment: Don't you have any worked out examples at hand? Please add your work in the main post or this will likely get closed.

Comment: I edited the main post so that it reflects what I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ is the sample and $L(\theta,\sigma^2\mid x)$ is the likelihood function given $x$.

Then likelihood ratio test statistic for testing $H_0$ vs $H_1$ is

\begin{align}
\Lambda(x)&=\frac{\sup_{\theta\le 0,\sigma^2}L(\theta,\sigma^2\mid x)}{\sup\limits_{\theta,\sigma^2}L(\theta,\sigma^2\mid x)}
\\&=\frac{L(\tilde\theta,\tilde\sigma^2\mid x)}{L(\hat\theta,\hat\sigma^2\mid x)}\,,
\end{align}

where $(\hat\theta,\hat\sigma^2)$ is the (unrestricted) MLE of $(\theta,\sigma^2)$, and $(\tilde\theta,\tilde\sigma^2)$ is the restricted MLE when $\theta\le 0$.

Indeed, $\hat\theta=\bar x=\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $\hat\sigma^2=\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i-\hat\theta)^2$.

Now argue that $$\tilde\theta=\begin{cases}\hat\theta&,\text{ if }\hat\theta\le 0 \\ 0&,\text{ if }\hat\theta>0\end{cases}\,,$$ so that $$\tilde\sigma^2=\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i-\tilde\theta)^2=\begin{cases}\hat\sigma^2&,\text{ if }\hat\theta\le 0 \\ \frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2&,\text{ if }\hat\theta>0\end{cases}$$

Simplify $\Lambda$ from here and reject $H_0$ for small values of $\Lambda$. When $\Lambda=1$, we trivially fail to reject $H_0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, the question is, how do I show that the test is size $\alpha$ (i.e. $\alpha = sup_{\theta \leq 0} P\left(\frac{\bar X}{\sqrt{S^2/n}} > t_{n-1,\alpha}\right)$) using $\Lambda$?