# GLRT for a one-sided composite hypothesis for $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, $H_0 : \sigma \leq \sigma_0$

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

This is sort of related to (different hypothesis though): [GLRT statistic for composite normal hypothesis, two unknowns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553626/glrt-statistic-for-composite-normal-hypothesis-two-unknowns)
[GLRT statistic for composite normal hypothesis, two unknowns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553626/glrt-statistic-for-composite-normal-hypothesis-two-unknowns)

## Problem

I am struggling with defining a generalized likelihood ratio test for $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where $\mu$ is **unknown** and our hypothesis test is $H_0 : \sigma \leq \sigma_0$ vs $H_1 : \sigma > \sigma_0$.

## Attempt

I know that I need to find a test statistic in this form:

$$
\lambda(x) = \dfrac{\sup_{H_0} L(\mu,\sigma | x)}{\sup_{H_0 \cup H_1} L(\mu,\sigma | x)}
$$

I know that I can do this by way of MLEs.  As shown in the link above, the 2 MLEs are $(\bar{X}, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2)$.  Specifically, for $\sigma$, the MLE would be $\hat{\sigma}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2)}$.

My thinking is that the MLE $\hat{\sigma}$ would be the denominator for $\lambda(x)$.

## Issue

I am lost with what to do with the numerator.  My suspicion is that it follows similarly to the link I posted where we have $\lambda(x) = 1$ when $\hat{\sigma} \leq \sigma_0$.

I am not sure what happens when $\hat{\sigma} > \sigma_0$.

My shot in the dark is that we have a test statistic defined as follows:

$$
\lambda(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \hat{\sigma} \leq \sigma_0 \\
\dfrac{L(\mu, \sigma_0 | x)}{L(\mu, \hat{\sigma} | x)} & \hat{\sigma} > \sigma_0
\end{cases}
$$

Or something like that.