# Likelihood ratio test: normal for unknown variance

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

> Let  $X_1,\dots,X_n\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, $\sigma^2$ is unknow. We
>   want to test
>
> $H_0:\mu=5$  vs $H_1:\mu>5 $
>
> ---

$$f_{\theta}(\vec{x})=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right)^n\exp\left[-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]$$

$\underset{\sigma^2\geq 0 ,\;\mu\in\theta}{\sup}f_\theta(\vec{x})$

$$\ln f_\theta(\vec{x})=-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2\right)-\frac{n\ln 2\pi\sigma^2}{2}$$

$$\frac{\partial\ln f_\theta(\vec{x})}{\partial \mu}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu))=\frac{n(\bar{x}-\mu)}{\sigma^2}$$
Then

$$\frac{\partial\ln f_\theta(\vec{x})}{\partial\mu}=0\Leftrightarrow \frac{n(\bar{x}-\mu)}{\sigma^2}=0\Leftrightarrow \mu=\bar{x}\rightarrow \hat{\mu}=\bar{x}\hspace{0.25cm}\text{max or min?}$$

Because
$$\frac{\partial^2\ln f_\theta(\vec{x})}{\partial\mu^2}=-\frac{n}{\sigma^2}<0\hspace{0.5cm}\hat{\mu}\;\text{is a max}$$
Taking $\mu=\bar{x}$ we have 
$$\frac{\partial\ln f_\theta(\vec{x})}{\partial\sigma^2}=-\frac{n}{2\sigma^4}\left(\sigma^2-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2\right)$$
Then
$$\frac{\ln f_\theta(\vec{x})}{\sigma^2}=0\Leftrightarrow \sigma^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2\rightarrow\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2\hspace{0.25cm}\text{max or min?}$$
Because
$$\left.\frac{\partial^2\ln f_\theta(\vec{x})}{\partial (\sigma^2)^2}\right|_{\sigma^2=\hat{\sigma}^2}=-\frac{n^3}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})\right)^{-2}<0\hspace{0.5cm} \hat{\sigma}^2 \hspace{0.25cm}\text{it's a max}$$
Then 
$$\underset{\sigma^2\geq 0 ,\;\mu\in\theta}{\sup}f_\theta(\vec{x})=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hat{\sigma}^2}}\right)^n\exp\left[-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{2\hat{\sigma}^2}\right]=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hat{\sigma}^2}}\right)^ne^{-\frac{n}{2}}$$

---

$$\underset{\sigma^2\geq 0 ,\;\mu\in\theta_0}{\sup}f_\theta(\vec{x})$$
$$\hat{\sigma}_0^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu_0)^2$$
Then
$$\underset{\sigma^2\geq 0 ,\;\mu\in\theta_0}{\sup}f_\theta(\vec{x})=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hat{\sigma}_0^2}}\right)^n\exp\left[-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(x_i-\mu_0)^2}{2\hat{\sigma}_0^2}\right]=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hat{\sigma}_0^2}}\right)^ne^{-\frac{n}{2}}$$

So
$$\Lambda=\frac{\underset{\sigma^2\geq 0 ,\;\mu\in\theta_0}{\sup}f_\theta(\vec{x})}{\underset{\sigma^2\geq 0 ,\;\mu\in\theta}{\sup}f_\theta(\vec{x})}=\left(\frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\hat{\sigma}_0^2}\right)^{n/2}$$

Comment: Do you have any reason for the region to be same? It would be a right-tailed test which you can easily verify.

Comment: No, I haven't. I was reading a proof to find the rejection region for the case $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$ vs $H_1:\mu_1\neq\mu_0$ and I thought that proof will be the same for my case and I can't find where it's the difference btw how can I prove It would be a right-tailed test?

Comment: If your question is how to derive a likelihood ratio test for $H_1:\mu >5$, please show your work. Similar questions are likely answered here before.

Comment: What is wrong in my work?

Comment: See similar questions https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3553626/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3460264/321264.

Comment: Thank you , I'll see them